# Why is this unsigned int holding more data than it has memory for?

Tags: c++, memory, allocation

An unsigned `int` can only hold 32 bits of data. Why doesn't the compiler give an error when I assign a larger value to it than what it can hold?

I have tried other various values and it still gives no error.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int mem = 0x89678456543454345934;
    cout << mem;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the behaviour of unsigned integer overflow is well defined. Or are you asking why that is, as in, why did the designers of C++ not make this an error?

Comment: FWIW you probably should increase your warning level.

Comment: @wazeeer Because that is the way it is in C :-)

Comment: But, `mem` cannot hold more data than it has memory for. How did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: _"An unsigned `int` can only hold 32 bits of data"_ - No, it can hold [at _least_ 16 bits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) of data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because `0x89678456543454345934` is greater than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned_int>::max()`. However, `unsigned` types wrap around their maximum value, so if the right hand side is representable by an integer type you have well defined behaviour. In that case the result is `0x89678456543454345934` mod `std::numeric_limits<unsigned_int>::max`.

**EDIT**

The right hand side of your assignment is an [integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). To represent it, the compiler uses the first type (ordered wrt its size) in which the integer literal can fit. If there is no such type, then **the program is ill-formed**. The decimal value of your constant is:

```
648873758694578209446196L
```

On my machine, for both clang++ and g++ `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max()` is `18446744073709551615`, which is smaller than your constant. It seems that your program is then ill-formed, unless the compiler uses more than 64 bits to represent `unsigned long long`, which I highly doubt. As @juanchopanza remarked, clang++ refuses to compile the code, with the error

> error: integer constant is larger than the largest unsigned integer type

g++ however goes ahead and compiles it, emitting only a warning

> warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type

The warning is quite confusing, as it refers to the right hand side, not to the further conversion to `unsigned int`, for which you get

> warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]

On my machine `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` is `4294967295`, and therefore `648873758694578209446196L % 4294967295` is `3633002191L`. However when I run your program I get `1412716852`. This happens because the program is ill-formed, and unfortunately the compiler does not emit an error (it is not mandated by the standard) but only a warning.

Comment: Clang gives me a more relevant error: `error: integer literal is too large to be represented in any integer type`

Comment: yup g++ changes values of mem from 9535901844731353396 to 1412716852